# Javascript event bubbling

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-bubbling

I'm making a small site where if you click on the background, you get a colorpicker allowing you to change the background color.

The problem is that this colorpicker is now showing up no matter where I click, because of event bubbling. I doubt the solution here is adding "return false" to every single HTML element on the entire page. What can I do about this?

The Javascript:

```
var colorPicker = $.farbtastic('#colorpicker');

var bodyBackgroundColor = $('body').css('background-color').rgbToHex();

$('body').click(function() {
    //Set the link to the field displaying the chosen color.
    colorPicker.linkTo('#newcolor');

    //Set the color on the colorpicker wheel.
    colorPicker.setColor(bodyBackgroundColor);

    //Set oldcolor field values
    $('#oldcolor').val(bodyBackgroundColor);
    $('#oldcolor').css('background-color', bodyBackgroundColor);

    //Set newcolor field values
    $('#newcolor').val(bodyBackgroundColor);

    new Boxy($('#form_changecolor'));

    return false;
});
```

Here's an overview of what the HTML looks like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header"></div>
            <div id="content"></div>
            <div id="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
<html>
```

The page layout is such that the Header and footer background and same color and content is a different one.

Clicking on header or footer and changing that color changes both, because that color is actually the body-background. Content changes only content.

The problem with the delegate solution is that now is just doesn't work anymore at all. And the stoppropagation method basically does the same thing.

I need some propagation turned on, but not all of it.

Comment: It would help if you could provide some sort of image of the page, and indicate what parts of the page are places where "click" events would be targetting the `<body>` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to return false for every HTML element, only the ones that bubble to `body`, namely all of `body`'s children.

Try adding this:

```
$(function(){
    $("body").children().click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation()
    }); 
});
```

All clicks have to eventually bubble to `body`'s children (or else you clicked on `body` itself) and this will stop it from propagating further.

Comment: added some details to my original post.

Comment: @WebDevHobo, just so I'm understanding, you want clicking on `header` and `footer` to propagate to `body`, but not when you click on `content`?

Comment: Yes. I stop the content propagation by doing "return false" in the click() function for it, I think.

Comment: I've got it working. I just added the hyperlinks to the selector for stopPropagation, dumped the `children()` and I leave the rest clickable. Also, not using Pointy's code anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of handling the bubbling yourself, let jQuery do it:

```
$('body').delegate('body', 'click', function() {
  // your code
});
```

The jQuery code will verify that the event target matches the selector ("body") before continuing on with your code.

Comment: I added some details, since the initial code stopped the site from working

Comment: @WebDevHobo well, given your HTML, there is nothing on the page that exposes any of the `<body>` "surface".  Your "wrapper" `<div>` will surround the elements inside it, and the body will just be as big as that.  Thus, there's no place to put the mouse that would allow the body element to be the target of a "click" event.